# Botão Submit só funciona no segundo clique - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estou trabalhando com Laravel 8, mas sou muito novo ainda nesse framework, e me deparei com um problema que é um botão de submit que só envia minha solicitação no segundo click, no primeiro ele apenas recarrega a página, no segundo ele envia a solicitação e executa o comando normalmente.
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de painel administrativo para catálogo de serviços. Eu não sei o que pode estar ocasionando isso, ficarei grato se me ajudarem.
Sempre que clico no "X" que é o botão de excluir, ele recarrega a página e só funciona quando clico de novo. Ah, detalhe, esta tela é a continuação de outra. A primeira e segunda etapa é quando eu adiciono um serviço ao banco, e a terceira é quando eu faço a inserção de links em outra tabela que está relacionada, então quando finaliza as duas primeiras, eu redireciono para esta página para poder adicionar quantos links forem necesários.

Aqui é o meu formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O restante do link da tag `<a>` foi cortado mas não tem tanta importancia, é apenas a variável que irá exibir o nome do link.

Minha rota:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora este é meu controller:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta é a tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

primeiro você precisa adicionar um value a seu button, acredito que seja apagar, então:

```
<button type = "submit" value = "apagar" class = "bi bi-x p-1 btn btn-without-border">Apagar</button>
```

então tente utilizar o ajax como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        switch ($_POST['action']) {
            case 'apagar':
                apagar();
                break;
        }
    }

    function apagar() {
        echo "The apagar function is called.";
        exit;
    }

   
?>
```

aconselho que não coloque seu código como imagem, utilize o formato de código fornecido pela própria plataforma, facilita para que possamos compreender o problema e ajudar...

Comment: caso não resolver, teste o atributo "onclick", não me recordo se é aceito pelo php, mas não custa tentar ;)

Comment: Não entendi como vou aplicar este código ao meu controller, não tenho familiaridade com AJAX. E o `onclick` não funciona pra PHP.

Comment: você pode ver mais sobre ajax em: [AJAX](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-cadastro-com-php-ajax-e-jquery/28046)